# How to add same column name in excel sheet in EPPLUS library while creating excel

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, epplus-4

I am using EPPLUS library for creating excel file with a data table.
I have such column in my stored procedure: emp_name, sales, INR, marketing, INR
But in excel file it generates column name like with column name like emp_name, sales, INR, marketing, INR1 etc.
How do I prevent that to print whatever column name in the data table or any other configurations that I am missing?

Code:

```
        string BasePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BasePath"];
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx";
        string FilePath = BasePath + fileName;

        using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = 
            excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("WorkingReport");

            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(data,false);
            ws.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;

            ws.Column(1).Width = 10;
            ws.Column(2).Width = 20;
            ws.Column(3).Width = 20;
            ws.Column(4).Width = 20;

            FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(FilePath);
            ws.Protection.IsProtected = false;
            excel.SaveAs(excelFile);
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INR and INR1 is printed because your datatable has those columns. When same column is selected more than one time in a select list, SQL automatically aliases the column name by adding number at its end to distinguish between two columns. A datatable cannot have duplicate column names. In your case, second INR is being renamed to INR1. You could try

```
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(data,true); //"PrintHeaders" true instead of false
```

but I think you will get the same result.

If you can somehow manage to get cell address of header after data is loaded you can over write the value as
`ws.Cells["A5"].Value="INR"` 
will overwrite the "INR1". 
There are other ways also https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Addressing-a-worksheet

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need the excel file in such format, not a single chance to change column names!

Comment: column name + count is added by datatable or that modification is doing while creating excel?

Comment: If the postion of header in excel file is fixed, or some how you can find the address of header cell, then you can rename the text after the data is being loaded. sheet.Cells[CellAddress].Value = "INR";

Comment: Columnname+count is added by c# while creating datatable

Comment: Ok let me try above on because the no of column in the sheet is fixed

Comment: If it is fixed that second "INR" will always be fifth col the ws.Cells["A5"].Value="INR" will overwrite the "INR1". There are other ways also https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Addressing-a-worksheet

Comment: Above one is working please update your answer as per comment code. For the temporary purpose, its working and the change impact is also less in my case.